# JavaScript Stored Function on MongoDB Server

Tags: mongodb

This is related to javascript stored function in mongodb server. I know all the details about the working and use cases. I am doubtful about one line which is in the official documentation of MongoDB.

"Note : We do not recommend using server-side stored functions if possible."

Infact what I feel, after moving to V8 JavaScript engine ( improving concurrency issues for javascript queries ) and given the fact this may save us many network round trip time, why this is not recommended by 10gen?

Comment: I think the best place to bring this up is with 10gen directly. Did you try contacting them? (Maybe via their Jira bug database so the issue can be tracked). While I can say that it might be a useful feature in some scenarios, I can see how it could be easily abused and be difficult for 10gen to build and support in a sustainable and performance minded way.

Comment: @WiredPrairie : Yes, I will do that. First I will try mongodb-user google group. Thanks

Comment: any answer from 10gen? I would be very interested.

Comment: Stored procedure works very slow in MongoDB. For every matched document they have to run the JavaScript evaluation which they claim is slow. You can directly run one simple example query (one normal and other using some JavaScript) in your mongo shell to verify that this is actually slow.

Answer (score 0):

This is not recommended due to the fact that the javascript function needs to take write lock for the duration of it's executing meaning you'll cause potential bottle necks in your write performance.

Comment: You can optionally choose to provide 'nolock' option which will just take the read lock

Answer (score 0):

There are some disadvantages of stored procedures in general:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/462978/when-should-you-use-stored-procedures

Yet I understand your point concerning the network roundtrips.